# Wifi Scan Resultandroid.net.wifi.WifiManager@4249dfb0

Tags: android, android-wifi

When I debug my android studio project it is getting 
Wifi Scan Resultandroid.net.wifi.WifiManager@4249dfb0
what should I do to correct it? my android code is below

```
public class WifiService extends Service implements BluetoothDeviceListener,WiFiDeviceListener{

public WifiService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    BLEManager bleManager= new BLEManager(this);
    bleManager.scanLeDevice(25,25);
    //bleManager.stopLeDeviceScan();
    WiFiManager wiFiManager= new WiFiManager(this);
    wiFiManager.scanWiFiDevice(25,25);
    //wiFiManager.stopWiFiScan();



    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

}
@Override
public void onLeDeviceDiscovered(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList) {
    System.out.println("bluetooth enable notifications");
}
@Override
public void onWiFiDeviceDiscovered(ArrayList<WirelessFiDevice> deviceList) {
    System.out.println("wifi enable notifications");
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: I am working on beacon technology. I have made project in android studio that will send notifications when users will open their wifis. When I debugging my project I am getting Wifi Scan Resultandroid.net.wifi.WifiManager@4249dfb0

Comment: Can you provide some code? So that others, not only me, can answer you, and avoid downvote to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code will be following

public class WifiService extends Service implements BluetoothDeviceListener,WiFiDeviceListener{

public WifiService() {
}

@Override

public void onCreate() {

```
 BLEManager bleManager= new BLEManager(this);
bleManager.scanLeDevice(25,25);
//bleManager.stopLeDeviceScan();
WiFiManager wiFiManager= new WiFiManager(this);
wiFiManager.scanWiFiDevice(25,25);
//wiFiManager.stopWiFiScan();
```

}

@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

```
// TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.

throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
```

}

@Override

public void onLeDeviceDiscovered(ArrayList deviceList) {

```
System.out.println("bluetooth enable notifications");
```

}

@Override

public void onWiFiDeviceDiscovered(ArrayList deviceList) {

```
System.out.println("wifi enable notifications");
```

}

}